# Laravel Vapor Unable to Download DOCX or XLSX file types

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

I am using Laravel vapor to host my application, and I am having issue downloading certain file types from AWS S3. I'm wondering if this is a CloundFront issue with the request headers not allowing these file types. Since I am able to download PNG, JPG, PDF files fine, I just have issue with files like DOCX & XLSX. In my API I am just using the Storage facade to stream the download.

```php
    /**
     * Download file from storage
     * @param Document $document
     * @return StreamedResponse
     */
    public function download(Document $document): StreamedResponse
    {
        return Storage::disk('s3')->download($document->path);
    }
```

Here are the request header which I believe are set

```
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
```

This is the error that is thrown

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to resolve by making a temporary link to the item in S3 storage, and redirect away for initialize download.

```php
    public function download(Document $document): RedirectResponse
    {
        $url = Storage::temporaryUrl(
            $document->path
            now()->addMinutes(30)
        );

        return Redirect::away($url);
    }
```

Refernce from Vapor Docs: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/development.html#binary-responses